# Apache Spark - GROUP BY

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to achieve the below functionality in Apache Spark using Scala. I have a set of sample records like this.

[image]

Note that the EffectiveDate column is sometimes blank and also different for the same CustomerID.

Now, as output, I want one record per CustomerID where the EffectiveDate is the MAX. So, for the above example, i want the records highlighted as shown below.

[image]

Can anyone please provide a script in Spark(using scala) to achieve the above output. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please remove that image and put data as an text? And what have you tried so far and what did not work?

Comment: first you can filter effectiveDate records with blank then groupBy("customerId").agg(max_("EffectiveDate"))) ....

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. If your `EffectiveDate` column is already a date then omit the cast to date step.

```
           val df = spark.createDataFrame(
                Seq(
                    (1, "John", 28, "M", "1-Jan-15" ),
                    (1, "John", 28, "M", "1-Feb-15" ),
                    (1, "John", 28, "M", "" ),
                    (1, "John", 28, "M", "1-Mar-14" ),
                    (2, "Jane", 25, "F", "5-Mar-14" ),
                    (2, "Jane", 25, "F", "5-Jun-15" ),
                    (2, "Jane", 25, "F", "3-Feb-14" )
                    
                )
            ).toDF(
                "CustomerID", 
                "CustomerName",
                "Age",
                "Gender",
                "EffectiveDate"
            ).withColumn(
                "EffectiveDate",
                from_unixtime(
                    unix_timestamp(
                        col("EffectiveDate"), "dd-MMM-yy"), 
                    "YYYY-MM-dd").cast("date")
)               
            
            df.show()
        /*
        +----------+------------+---+------+-------------+
        |CustomerID|CustomerName|Age|Gender|EffectiveDate|
        +----------+------------+---+------+-------------+
        |         1|        John| 28|     M|   2015-01-01|
        |         1|        John| 28|     M|   2015-02-01|
        |         1|        John| 28|     M|         null|
        |         1|        John| 28|     M|   2014-03-01|
        |         2|        Jane| 25|     F|   2014-03-05|
        |         2|        Jane| 25|     F|   2015-06-05|
        |         2|        Jane| 25|     F|   2014-02-03|
        +----------+------------+---+------+-------------+
        */
            
            val df_agg = df.groupBy("CustomerID", "CustomerName","Age", "Gender" ).agg(max("EffectiveDate"))  
            df_agg.show()
        
        /*
        +----------+------------+---+------+------------------+
        |CustomerID|CustomerName|Age|Gender|max(EffectiveDate)|
        +----------+------------+---+------+------------------+
        |         2|        Jane| 25|     F|        2015-06-05|
        |         1|        John| 28|     M|        2015-02-01|
        +----------+------------+---+------+------------------+
        */
```